# Make a Cocoa application quit when the main window is closed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

**How to make a Cocoa application quit when the main window is closed?** Without that you have to click on the app icon and click quit in the menu.

Comment: Although this is a valid question, reconsider doing it. If your app needs to have its main window always present, disable the ability to close it instead.

Comment: Fair enough, I will do that. Thank you!

Comment: I disagree. In most single-window apps, including Calculator and (nowadays) System Preferences, you are allowed to close the window, and doing so quits the application. And I have personally used apps that went the other way, and been frustrated when I tried to close the main window and got a beep instead of the close/quit I wanted.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can implement `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:` to return YES in your app's delegate. But I would think twice before doing this, as it's really unusual on the Mac outside of small "utility" applications like Calculator and most Mac users will not appreciate your app behaving so strangely.

Comment: Actually, Apple rejected my application once and suggested I implement this. They said I needed either a clear way to re-open the main window, or implement "applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed"

Comment: @nute: Well, yes, there should be an easy way to reopen a window. An app where you click on the icon and nothing apparent happens is not good UX. That's a far cry from saying that apps in general should quit when the last window closes.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of how to close the application when the MAIN WINDOW is closed - this only addresses the issue when the LAST WINDOW is closed.

Answer (score 17):

Add this code snippet to your app's delegate:

```
-(BOOL) applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)app {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You are saved my time and life! Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

As the question is mainly about Cocoa programming and not about a specific
language (Objective-C), here is the Swift version of Chuck's and Steve's
answer:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // Your other application delegate methods ...

}
```

For **Swift 3** change the method definition to

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I have added this answer in the spirit of the meta question [Are new Swift answers on old Objective-C questions beneficial?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303338/are-new-swift-answers-on-old-objective-c-questions-beneficial), and because I closed a newer question asking explicitly for Swift code as duplicate of this one.

Comment: Swift 3 requires an underscore and space before the sender text.

Answer (score 8):

You should have an IBOutlet to your main window. For Example: IBOutlet NSWindow *mainWindow;

```
- (void)awakeFromWindow {
    [mainWindow setDelegate: self];
}
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [NSApp terminate:self];
}
```

If this does not work you should add an observer to your NSNotificationCenter for the Notification *NSWindowWillCloseNotification*. Don't forget to check if the right window is closing.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
extension MainWindowController: NSWindowDelegate {
    func windowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let window = notification.object as? NSWindow, let controller = window.windowController {

            if window == self.window {

                for window in self.childWindows {

                    print(" Closing \(window)")
                    window.close()

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```